# How to Compile with Embedded Font in Latex and Preserve Figures?

Tags: compiling, ieeetran, font-encodings, ieee-style, embedding

Using kile in linux platform and IEEE Transaction document type.

I need to include some figures from matlab eps format, with complicated formattings inside the figures. So I am using a command like

```
\epsfxsize=0.5\textwidth \leavevmode\epsffile{figurefile}
```

Also I am using some pstricks figure.

The problems are

- When I am compiling from kile, using latex, bibtex, dvi2ps and ps2pdf, then the fonts are not embedded, which is absolutely essential for me.
- When I am compiling from kile using pdflatex, the pstricks figures are totally messed up.
- When I am compiling from my terminal using `dvips -Ppdf -G0 -tletter filename.dvi`, the matlab figures do not show the axes.

There are so many parameters, I am totally at loss. What I need is my figures to appear correctly with the given command, the pstricks to appear correctly, and the font embedded. Any idea about how to compile?

If there was such a free online service which can somehow embed fonts in a PDF, that would solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I just did same in R and a dissertation template. You must embed fonts in the pdf image output from Matlab first. Then compile latex with pdflatex and fonts for doc will be included. Fonts from images will come along for free, as it were. If you can't get Matlab to do it, ghostscript can. If you have trouble on that, let me know.  I have a shell script for that, if you use Linux.